# A programmaticaly created div in jquery needs an extra click before i can click its p element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an input field inside a div:

```
<div id="fields">
  <input class="letters" type="text" name="lettersField" value="" />
</div>
```

and some jquery for it

```
$("#fields").on("change paste keyup focus", ".letters", function(){
  // A new div is created with some p elements inside it like so
  $("body").append('<div id="suggestions"></div>');
  $("#suggestions").html("<p>words</p>");
});
```

Then finally i want to call a click event on those "p" elements like so:

```
$("body").on("click", "p", function(){
  console.log("p element clicked");
});
```

The problem i am facing is that i need to click the "p" element TWICE for the FIRST time that the console.log appears, then when the input loses focus, i can click the "p" element and for each click have a console.log appear. Also, if i first click the input field, then click another input field or something else, and then go back to clicking the "p" element, it then logs the click on the first click (that's why i think that the input losing focus has something to do with the double click required).

I am not only interested in a specific solution to my problem, but also possibly a general understanding of what is happening here, if anyone could be bothered that would be awesome. Thanks in advance!!!

UPDATE FROM MY COMMENT

> Hello again, i now noticed something, after running your codepen
>   again, give focus to the input field, then type "asd" on it, and THEN
>   try to click on the "p" element, that should reproduce the problem.

ANOTHER UPDATE FROM MY COMMENT

> Hello once again, i managed to solve my problem by removing the
>   "change" event and leaving the rest events in tact (i had originally
>   also added a flag variable to create the window only once). Thanks
>   again for the help, if someone knows any more information on why the
>   "change" event would do that i would welcome it.

Comment: I copied your code in the on-page editor of Stack Overflow and it worked fine on the first click. I'm guessing there is some other code on your page that interferes.

Comment: I can't reproduce this problem. See [the Codepen](http://codepen.io/rishatmuhametshin/pen/WpxamR?editors=1010#0). Notice that I changed `console.log` to `alert` to detect the moment `p` element is clicked more visually. Both in Chrome and Safari, the first click on `p` after it appears causes the function to be executed and alert being displayed.

Comment: Ok, you are correct, i really don't want to force everyone to read my clunky code so i will try to start from the ground up and add all of my code gradually to discover where the problem is first occured, if i get a definite solution i will update it here, thanks a lot for your answer!

Comment: Hello again, i now noticed something, after running your codepen again, give focus to the input field, then type "asd" on it, and THEN try to click on the "p" element, that should reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hello once again, i managed to solve my problem by removing the "change" event and leaving the rest events in tact (i had originally also added a flag variable to create the window only once). Thanks again for the help, if someone knows any more information on why the "change" event would do that i would welcome it.